# Graphs in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have modeled a winding process in Delphi xe-6, which involves several parameters as input and after the calculations, the plot procedure plots the outputs but I wanted to see how a particular graph responds when any one or more parameters are changed (with the existing curve from the previous calculation). To make that possible I didn't clear the series in the plot procedure and somehow I got an entire region between two lines. When I zoomed in, I found out that the whole blue region is a network of lines connecting the points of the two calculations and I want to show just two curves (not the network lines). Any suggestions?[image: Sample image of plot]

```
procedure TForm5.PlotValues;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  i:= 1;
      for i := 0 to Nmax do
        begin
          Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(r[i], p[i], '', clTeeColor);
          Chart2.Series[0].AddXY(r[i], Tt[i], '', clTeeColor);
          Chart3.Series[0].AddXY(r[i], Tw[i], '', clTeeColor);
          Chart4.Series[0].AddXY(r[i], Torq_app, '', clTeeColor);
          Chart4.Series[1].AddXY(r[i], Torq_cap[i], '', clTeeColor);
          if RadioGroup3.ItemIndex = 0 then
            begin
              Chart5.Series[0].AddXY(r[i], W_3Rq[i], '', clTeeColor);
              Chart5.Series[1].AddXY(r[i], W_Rq[i], '', clTeeColor);
            end;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a new series for the modified-parameter results.

Comment: @TOndrej But that's the point, I run a calculation using the 'calculation' button and then I change the value of one parameter and press the 'calculation' button again to see the difference. How can I create a new series while I am still in the compile mode (pressing F9 only once for the two simulations)? Maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Please add your code and images.

Comment: @KromStern sorry was busy, couldn't reply. The image posted here shows some sort of shaded area but when it is zoomed what we see is a network of lines. Just can't understand why?

Comment: I removed the generic "Pascal" tag, as this has nothing to do with "Pascal". Delphi is a separate language altogether; Pascal doesn't have a `TForm`, doesn't have an XE6 version, and doesn't have `TChart`. This question is specific to Delphi and XE6.